# Tag merge request: [tiles2] [apache-tiles]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

- [tiles2](/questions/tagged/tiles2)
- [apache-tiles](/questions/tagged/apache-tiles)
- <strike>[tiles](/questions/tagged/tiles)</strike>

is absolutely same (**[Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/)**), should merge to [apache-tiles](/questions/tagged/apache-tiles) or synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I would disagree that [tiles](/questions/tagged/tiles) should become a synonym, though I do agree that [tiles2](/questions/tagged/tiles2) should.  "Tiles" has too many other programming-related meanings to make it a synonym of [apache-tiles](/questions/tagged/apache-tiles).

- map tiles
- tile-based games
- windows phone "live tiles"
- and others.

---

With the edit, and [tiles](/questions/tagged/tiles) removed from the suggestion, I wholeheartedly agree (+1).  And since it's a small tag, there's nobody with enough rep in that tag to even suggest the tag synonym in the first place, so it's something that the moderators would have to take care of.